# How to ensure that a member variable is initialized before calling a class method

Tags: c++

There's a class with a parametrized constructor that initializes a member variable. All public methods of the class then use this member variable to do something.

I want to ensure that the caller always creates an object using the parametrized constructor (there is also a setter for this member variable) and then call that object's methods. In essence, it should be impossible for the caller to call any method without setting a value to the member variable (either by using the parametrized constructor or the setter). Here's the catch - there is just one method that itself generates a value to be initialized in the member variable (and returns it) - and to call that function, one would need a default constructor.

Currently, a caller can simply make an object using the default constructor and then call that object's method - I want to avoid checking whether or not the member variable is set in each and every one of the 20-odd methods of the class (and throw an exception if it is not) - except for the one method mentioned above.

Though a runtime solution is acceptable (better than the one I mentioned above); a compile-time solution is preferable so that any developer will not be allowed to make that mistake and then waste hours debuggging it!

Update: Here's an artist's impression of the current implementation in code:

```
class MyClass
{
private:
string m_strProperty;

void InternalNonStaticMethod(int iSomeParam);

public:
MyClass(string strValue)
{
m_strProperty = strValue;
}

MyClass() {}

void setProperty(string strValue)
{
    m_strProperty = strValue;
}

string MethodOddManOut()
{
    /* Do some computations to generate a value for the property */
    string strGeneratedValue("");
    InternalNonStaticMethod(4);
    /* ... */
    return strGeneratedValue;  // The value has to be returned and this method cannot simply update the member due to design issues that are beyond the realm of this question
}

void MethodLikeEveryoneElse()
{
    /* Do some computation based on the property */
    string strTemp = m_strProperty + "EXTEND";

    /* If strProperty is empty/garbage then this is going to fail miserably
       Trying to avoid the following snippet at 20 other similar methods:
       if (!strProperty.empty()) {
           strTemp = m_strProperty + "EXTEND";
       } else {
           throw exception
       }
    */
}

void MethodLikeEveryoneElse2()
{
    /* Similar to the above method */
}

}
```

The caller would be a function in some other class using it like this:

```
void MethodThatUsesThis()
{
    MyClass objA;
    m_strHandle = objA.MethodOddManOut();  // Save the handle as a member of this object

    /* Some other lines of code */

    objA.setProperty(strHandle);
    objA.MethodLikeEveryoneElse();
}

void AnotherMethodThatUsesThisLater(string strHandle)
{
    MyClass objA(strHandle);  // The handle that the above method received was passed to this method since they are in different classes
    objA.MethodLikeEveryoneElse2();
}
```

This code snippet is bound to raise tons of allegations on the horrendous design that is being implemented - but my only defense is, this is legacy code (ha! you saw this coming) and I only have the right to change anything in class A (it's more of an API and a library module) but the caller is not in my jurisdiction.

Comment: The usual solution is to make the default constructor private or not to have one at all. Do you need something more complicated?

Comment: If you absolutely need something to be initialized for the object to function, why on earth are you offering constructors which don't initialize this?

Comment: Something else to ask yourself: why are you offering a way to set the variable outside of the constructor if it needs to be initialized anyway?

Comment: If you provide a constructor a default one will not be automatically generated for you. I'm not sure what you're worried about.

Comment: I thought about what KilianFoth said - Oops! Sorry I forgot an important detail - there is just one method that itself generates a value to be initialized in the member variable - and to call that function, one would need a default constructor.

You would say, make that method static! Can't - that calls another non-static private method (that would just lead to a domino effect).

Comment: jzx, that member may be updated by the caller *between* calls to different methods, hence the setter.

Comment: @OmkarEkbote Add all important details to the question body.

Answer (score 1):

If `MethodOddManOut()` does not take arguments, just call it in your default constructor:

```
class MyClass {
     // ...
     public:

     MyClass() : m_strProperty( MethodOddManOut()) {}

     // ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
   class A {
     static const INVALID_PROPERTY_VALUE = -1; //null_ptr for non-primitives?
     int property;
     public :
     explicit A (int initialPropertyValue):
       property(initialPropertyValue) {
        if (initialPropertyValue == INVALID_PROPERTY_VALUE)
          throw illegal_argument("property can't be unset");
     }
     int setProperty(int newValue) {
        if (newValue == INVALID_PROPERTY_VALUE)
          throw illegal_argument("property can't be unset");
        int rv = property;
        property = newValue;
        return rv;
     }
   }

   int main() {
     A a(56);
     a.doSome();
     a.setProperty(-1); // fails early, requires no long debug when property is used
     a.doNext();
   }
```

Comment: I've added a code snippet explaining the situation to the question. One of the reasons I cannot use this answer is that I need to use the default constructor, without setting a value to the member, for one of the methods that doesn't need to property but generates it instead.

Answer (score -2):

This is the approache taken to get around the problem (better solutions are still welcome):

Write a private getter for the member in question that validates it's value and throws an exception. Use this getter in all member functions instead of directly using the member.

```
private:
hstring GetProperty()
{
    if (m_strProperty.empty()) {
        throw exception;
    } else {
        return m_strProperty;
    }
}

public:
void MethodLikeEveryoneElse()
{
    /* Do some computation based on the property */
    string strTemp = GetProperty() + "EXTEND";

    /* If strProperty is empty/garbage then this is going to fail miserably
       Trying to avoid the following snippet at 20 other similar methods:
       if (!strProperty.empty()) {
           strTemp = m_strProperty + "EXTEND";
       } else {
           throw exception
       }
    */
}
```

This is still susceptible to programmer error (some developer may accidentally use the member variable directly) and is a runtime solution rather than a compile-time enforcement.